# Access second table data using SQL Join

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, `Members` and `GroupMembers`.
I FullName from `Members` and `MemberID` from `GroupMembers` , but I don't know how to modify this query to achieve that:

```
SELECT FullName
FROM Members
INNER JOIN GroupMembers ON Members.ID=GroupMembers.MemberID
WHERE GroupMembers.GroupID = 'foo'
```

It gives `Members.FullName`, but also I need `GroupMembers.ID` on `Members.ID=GroupMembers.MemberID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that second column to your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT 
    m.FullName, gm.ID
FROM 
    Members m
INNER JOIN 
    GroupMembers gm ON m.ID = gm.MemberID
WHERE 
    gm.GroupID = 'foo'
```

Once you've created this join between the two tables, all columns from both tables are available to be selected, if need be.

I've also chosen to use **table aliases** in this `SELECT` statement - while it's not necessarily needed, I believe it makes things a lot more readable and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Members.FullName, GroupMembers.ID
FROM Members
INNER JOIN GroupMembers ON Members.ID=GroupMembers.MemberID
WHERE GroupMembers.GroupID = 'foo'
```